# Python & SQLite3 - output.sqlite in not saved as a databse

Tags: python, sqlite

I am exercising in Python with SQLite3 package to learn how to manupulate data and I come across an issue by saving output of sqlite files in a database format that I could not figure out how to do it, in order to run  on sqlite DB browser. I surfed in the Internet, but couldn't find an answer on my question.
Could someone have a look at the code I provided below and help me to solve it?

Here is my code:

```
import sqlite3 as sql

add = sql.connect('addressdb.sqlite')  # The file contains all necessary information
out = add.cursor()
out.execute('''SELECT Status.title, People.name, Address.phone, Kids.name 
FROM Status
JOIN Kids
JOIN Address
JOIN People
ON Status.kids_id = Kids.id AND Status.address_id = Address.id AND Address.people_id = People.id
WHERE  Status.title = "official of the government" OR Status.title = "Migrant" OR Status.title = "staff member/employee of the immigration service"
ORDER BY People.name DESC;''')

res = out.fetchall()
for save in res :
    print(save) # The output
```

#Here how I saved the output of the sqlite file:

```
storing = open('output.sqlite', 'w') # or ('output.db', 'w')
storing.write(str(save))
storing.close()

add.commit()
add.close()
```

When I open the saved file to run on SQlite DB Browser, the Db Browser pops up an error. Here is the image.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EZiQf.png)

Comment: try opening the `addressdb.sqlite`, not the `output.sqlite` in your SQLite DB Browser.

Comment: The output is not saved in addressdb..sqlite and when I rund it I have whole file.

Comment: Why do you think that `output.sqlite` file is a database? Open it in your favorite text editor.

Comment: @Shawn I want to save it in a database format to run on SQLite DB Browser. But the issue is it is not runnig on db browser reffering to the wrong format.

Comment: @AKA The output will not be in .sqlite format. 

If you just want to view the data. Why don't you open the `addressdb.sqlite` in your SQLite DB Browser, and then run the same query that you ran in your python code over there in SQLite browser itself?

You'll have the answer. You can't take a data dump out of an SQLite DB and view it in a DB Browser. That's not how it works. 
You need the DB to view a DB, not data from the DB. I hope it makes sense.

Comment: @Harpeet Singh Yes, I understood it, but as I wrote above I am exercising it in Python and was wandering if it is possible to store the text format files or its output in a sqlite format in Python to run on DB Bworser, is it possible to store the output of  sqlite files as database format to run  on DB Brwoser?

Comment: If you want to save the results of a query in a table in another database, you have to create it, attach it, and use one of the create table or insert forms that work with a select .

Comment: @Shawn Thank you. I am going to try it. I hope it comes off.